# Github actions filter jobs or steps by push path

Tags: github-actions

We've got some actions that it makes sense to logically group in one workflow, but not all of them need to run all the time.

I'm aware of

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'docs/**'
```

Is there a way to apply this information at the level of a particular job or step?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can use actions like [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) to build this behavior.

Comment: Is it still the case that out of the box can't do this in 2023?

Comment: This is one of the most illogical and frustrating design decisions by GitHub. You firstly have to specify how workflows are triggered, then again whether or not they are required. Which means that all path filtering is basically rendered useless.